# JPA: Group by and select function in Postgres

Tags: postgresql, jpa

I have a simple reporting query group by id and day that looks like the following:

```
select id,
    avg(case when name = 'temp' then value end) as average_temp,
    DATE_TRUNC('day', timestamp) as day
from data
group by id, day
order by id;
```

The query basically needs to show the average daily temperature for each asset.

The user is able to specify a bunch of different aggregation functions beyond just 'average', the above is only a simple example. For example, avg temp, max temp, max speed, etc.

I'm trying to translate that into JPA as follows:

```
CriteriaQuery<Object[]> query = criteriaBuilder.createQuery(Object[].class);
Root<AssetMetricDataPoint> root = query.from(Data.class);

List<Selection<?>> selectionList = getSelections(aggregationQuery, criteriaBuilder, root);

Expression<Instant> groupDate = criteriaBuilder.function("date_trunc", Instant.class, criteriaBuilder.literal("day"), root.get("timestamp"));

selectionList.add(groupDate.alias("day"));

query.multiselect(selectionList);
query.where(getWherePredicates(aggregationQuery, criteriaBuilder, root));
query.orderBy(getOrderBy(aggregationQuery, criteriaBuilder, root));
query.groupBy(root.get("id"), groupDate);

return this.setupPagination(entityManager.createQuery(query), aggregationQuery);
```

I'm using `criteriaBuilder.function` to group by the date. However, when I execute the query using JPA I get the following exception:

`org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: ERROR: column "data0_.timestamp" must appear in the GROUP BY clause or be used in an aggregate function`

This appears to occur because the query is parametized and Postgres doesn't realize that the 'day' parameter that appears in both the `select` and `group by` clauses are the same.

Is there any way around this. Can I somehow bake in the 'day' value so it's not sent a parameter? Or some other method?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the end there's a relatively solution to the problem. Rather than grouping by the expression, I thought I'd try to group by the alias instead: `criteriaBuilder.literal("day")`. This didn't work, however, with Postgres complaining about a non-integer literal.

I then realised I could group by a positional integer instead, which in my case ended up looking like:

```
query.groupBy(root.get("id"), criteriaBuilder.literal(selectionList.size()));
```

This works as expected.